# Controlling Content Control Checkboxes Using Userform Checkboxes

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word

I have a word document with 5 check box content controls - these are used to show which options have been selected (or not) when the document is pdf'd and/or printed. They themselves don't actually need to 'do' anything, code wise.

I have a userform which has 5 checkboxes, which corresepond to the 5 check boxes within the document. The user can select any, none, or all of these userform checkboxes, and I want the word document content control check boxes to match.

For the sake of simplicity I have named the content control checkboxes the same as the userform checkboxes, in a hope to loop through the code once I get it working.

The following works when opening the userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim x As Variant
    Dim z As control

On Error GoTo quit

    For Each x In Array("ChkA", "ChkB", "ChkC", "ChkD", "ChkE")
        For Each z In Me.Controls
            If z.Name = x And ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(x).Item(1).Checked = True Then z.Value = True
        Next z
    Next x

quit:

End Sub
```

This does technically work, but is a little ineligent, since there is only one instance of "ChkA", or "ChkB", etc, but this code loops through each name for each checkbox, meaning it's performing 25 checks when really it only needs to be doing 5.

However, when trying to move the checkbox values from the userform back into the word document, the 'same' code above (but reversed) doesn't work, i.e.:

```
Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()

    Dim x As Variant
    Dim z As control

    For Each x In Array("ChkA", "ChkB", "ChkC", "ChkD", "ChkE")
        For Each z In Me.Controls
            If z.Name = x And z.Value = True Then ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(x).Item(1).Checked = True
        Next z
    Next x

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

This gives a type mismatch error on the "For Each z ..." line.

What I want to be able to do is refer to my userform checkboxes with a variable name, so that I can loop through them, something like the following maybe?

```
    Dim x as Variant
    Dim y as String
    Dim z as control

    x = Array("ChkA", "ChkB", "ChkC", "ChkD", "ChkE")

    For i = 0 To 4
        y = x(i)
        Set z = Me.Controls(y)
        ActiveDocument.FormFields(y).CheckBox.Value = z.Value
        Set z = Nothing
    Next i
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the checkboxes in the document and on the UserForm have corresponding names there is no need to use an array. Simply loop through the controls on the UserForm and use the control names to address the content controls.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ctl As MSForms.Control

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If Left(ctl.Name, 3) = "Chk" Then
      ctl.Value = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(ctl.Name).Item(1).Checked
    End If
  Next ctl

End Sub

Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()

  For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If Left(ctl.Name, 3) = "Chk" Then
      ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(ctl.Name).Item(1).Checked = ctl.Value
    End If
  Next ctl

  Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, for those interested:

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Variant
Dim z As control

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    On Error Resume Next

    x = Array("ChkA", "ChkB", "ChkC", "ChkD", "ChkE") 'names of both userform and content control checkboxes

    For i = 0 To 4
        Set z = Me.Controls(x(i))
        If ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(x(i)).Item(1).Checked = True Then z.Value = True
    Next i

    Set z = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()

    On Error Resume Next

    x = Array("ChkA", "ChkB", "ChkC", "ChkD", "ChkE") 'names of both userform and content control checkboxes

    For i = 0 To 4
        Set z = Me.Controls(x(i))
        If z.Value = True Then
            ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(x(i)).Item(1).Checked = True
        Else
            ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(x(i)).Item(1).Checked = False
        End If
    Next i

    Set z = Nothing

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

This now does what I need it to do, and I can expand on it as planned. Hope it proves useful for someone.